# Is there a way to programmatically determine if the android device is IPv6 enabled or not?

Tags: android, ipv6

I used NetworkInterface class to determine the ip addresses but although the device is IPv4 enabled only, I retrieve IPv6 addresses as well as IPv4 addresses from the networkInterface since the router assigns IPv6 address as well.
Is there a way to programmatically determine if the android device is IPv6 enabled or not?

Comment: dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143152/995320

Comment: I tried that already. it gives me IPv6 addresses as well on my device although my device doesn't support IPv6 because the router assigns fake ipv6 addresses in the local network. I want to find a way that tells me if the device supports or not.

Comment: Could that mean the device supports it, but it's actually the network which does not?  Which do you really care to know about - the device itself, or the device in its current network ecosystem?

Comment: I want to know about the device itself

Comment: In that case it is simple: if your device has an IPv6 address it supports IPv6. It might only have a loopback `::1` or an `fe80:` link-local address. If it has any of those then the device support IPv6.

Comment: That's not a "fake" IPv6 address. It's very real, and it means your device does support IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "enabled".

**Checking if the current network supports:**

If the interface has an IPv6 address for which `Inet6Address.isSiteLocal()`, `.isLinkLocal()` and `.isLoopback()` return false, then the device thinks it has an upstream router on that interface, and that router thinks there's a connection to the general network. Both may be wrong of course, but they think what they think.

Strictly speaking, this tests whether the device is connected to a router that claims to be connected to the IPv6 world. That router might be wrong.

**Checking if the device supports:**

If you want to want to know whether the Android device has any v6 support at all, no matter whether it's able to reach other v6 devices, then you could iterate over the network interfaces and check whether any of them have any Inet6Address-es. I expect that the loopback interface would have a v6 address even if the other interfaces do not.

Comment: This will only work if the device is *currently* connected to the ipv6 network right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it tests whether the device is connected to a router that claims to be connected to the IPv6 world. That router might be wrong. If you want to want to know whether the Android device has any v6 support at all, no matter whether it's able to reach other v6 devices, then you could iterate over the network interfaces and check whether any of them have any Inet6Address-es. I can't test (have only v6-capable networks), but I expect that the loopback interface would have a v6 address even if the other interfaces do not.